# C#: Consumiendo un web services SOAP me da error 405

Tags: c#, soap

Estoy tratando de consumir un servicio web SOAP con C# VS2017, pero me da el siguiente mensaje "Error en el servidor remoto: (405) Método no permitido".
Averiguando dice que ese error es porque el servidor no soporta POST, pero el servidor si permite en método POST porque realice pruebas del XML en SoapUI 5.5 y funcionó 100% (también probé con GET pero no funciona).
Para comprobar si mi código tenia algún problema lo probé con el webservice https://www.satan.lt/WebServices/Time.asmx y sus respectivos cambios en XML y funcionó sin problemas, pero cuando utilizo la URL privada la que debo consumir, me envía error 405.

No estoy seguro si debo tener alguna configuración especial en el archivo App.config del proyecto en C#.

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código.

```
const string _url = "https://..........?WSDL";
const string _action = "http://..........Op";

public static void InvokeService()
{
    //Calling CreateSOAPWebRequest method
    HttpWebRequest WebRequest = CreateSOAPWebRequest();            
    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
    //SOAP Body Request 
    soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:SOAP-ENC=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
        <SOAP-ENV:Header> 
                    .............................
        </SOAP-ENV:Header> 
        <SOAP-ENV:Body>
                    .............................
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>");
    using (Stream stream = WebRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
    }                        
    // Sends the HttpWebRequest and waits for a response.
    using (HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            string webRequestStream = (new StreamReader(stream)).ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(webRequestStream);                       
        }  
        // Releases the resources of the response.
        httpResponse.Close();            }           
    }
}

public static HttpWebRequest CreateSOAPWebRequest()
{
    //Making Web Request 
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);   
    //SOAPAction
    webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction",_action);
    //Content_type
    webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
    //HTTP method
    webRequest.Method = "POST";            
    //return HttpWebRequest             
    return webRequest;
}
```

Comment: El servicio creado es tuyo?

Comment: El servicio fue creado por un tercero, otros clientes ya lo están utilizando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente pude resolver el problema, solo modifique lo siguiente:

```
using (var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(soapResult);  
    }
    httpResponse.Close();
}

public static HttpWebRequest CreateSOAPWebRequest()
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_url);
    webRequest.Headers.Add(@"SOAPAction", _action);          
    webRequest.ContentType = @"application/soap+xml; charset=""utf-8""";
    webRequest.Method = @"POST";
    return HttpWebRequest  
}
```